# Android - cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER) returns -1

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I have developed an app, which on my tests on Andoid emulators (from Android 10 to 12) works fine.

An user reported an app crash on their Android12 device. Looking into the log, the error happens to be that `cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)` returns -1.

Here the full code:

```
private void onClick(){
   Intent pickContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
   pickContact.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
   startActivityForResult(pickContact, CONTACT_PICK_CODE);
}

protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == CONTACT_PICK_CODE) {
        Uri contactData = data.getData();
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int phoneIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
        }
        c.close();
    }
}
```

What this code is trying to do is simply retrieving a phone number.

If for me it works well on my emulator, what could cause this issue on the user's device? Thank you!

Comment: Your `query()` call does not state what you want returned. You are assuming that the default set of columns contains the column that you wish. Apparently, that is not always the case. You might consider revising your `query()` call.