# Android - Unable to retrieve contact info if third app contacts is being used

Tags: android, android-contacts

my goal is to retrieve a contact's phone number after it gets picked in the contact list. This is the code I am using

```
private void onClick(){
   Intent pickContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
   pickContact.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
   startActivityForResult(pickContact, CONTACT_PICK_CODE);
}

protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == CONTACT_PICK_CODE) {
        Uri contactData = data.getData();
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int phoneIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
        }
        c.close();
    }
}
```

which works fine if the standard Android contacts app is being used, but crashes when the app "Simple Contacts" is being used.
In particular, the error happens because phoneIndex is -1.

How to make it work even if the user chooses to use another contact list app?
For reference, this is the cursor when the contact gets selected from Simple Contacts. [image]

As you can see it contains only 36 columns, while using the standard contact list app it has 84 columns, one of which is `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER`

Comment: See [my comment on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74240888/android-cursor-getcolumnindexcontactscontract-commondatakinds-phone-number-r#comment131073853_74240888). If you want `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER`, then try asking for it specifically in your `query()` call, rather than assuming that a `null` projection will give it to you.

Comment: yes, tried that, but does not work